# route and dd doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm new to Laravel and what i'm trying here is to simply get the input form values and display it with dd function.

routes file:

```
Route::get('/', [
  'as' => 'index', 
  "uses" => "IndexController@index"
]);

Route::get('/panier',[
  "uses" => "ProductController@addToCard"
]);
```

My form :

```
<form method="get" action"/panier">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Nombre de serveurs physiques
            </td>
            <td>
              <select id="nb_serveurs" name="nb_serveurs"><option value="0">Choisir une option</option><option value="1" selected="selected" >1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Type de licence
            </td>
            <td>
              <select id="type" name="type"><option value="0">Choisir une option</option><option value="1" selected="selected" >Illimitée</option><option value="2">Standard</option></select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Durée
            </td>
            <td>
              <select id="duree" name="duree"><option value="0">Choisir une option</option><option value="1" selected="selected">1 an</option><option value="2">2 ans</option><option value="3">3 ans</option></select>
              <a class="reset_variations" href="#">Effacer</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <div style="width:100%;height:50px;">
          <div class="price"><span id="total">495,00 € HT</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panier-button">
          <input type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt joli-boutton" id="panier-go" value="Ajouter au panier"/>
        </div>
</form>
```

And the controller :

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function addToCard (Request $request){
      $input = Input::all();
      dd($input);
    }
}
```

the get works because when i submit the form my URL goes like this :

http://127.0.0.1/altaro_laravel/public/?nb_serveurs=1&type=1&duree=1

But shouldn't it be like this ?

http://127.0.0.1/altaro_laravel/public/panier/?nb_serveurs=1&type=1&duree=1

and why the dd function doesn't work, it doesn't display anything ..

Sorry i'm a real newbie.

And 2nd question, how can i do this with post method, when i replace my route to post and the method form attribute it doesn't work.

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE:**

Ok change things a little bit :

here is the route :

```
Route::get('/panier',[
  "uses" => "ProductController@addToCard",
  "as" => "panier"
]);
```

Here is the form tag :

```
<form method="get" action="{{ route('panier') }}">
```

New controller function :

```
public function addToCard (Request $request){
      $input = $request->nb_serveurs;
      dd($input);
}
```

I unfortunatly have this error now :
"
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, to retrieve the input from your form, you should use $request. See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests)

So your function could be something like

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function addToCard (Request $request){
      $input = $request->nb_serveurs;
      dd($input);
    }
}
```

Note: there is a mistake in your form as well

```
<form method="get" action"/panier">
```

needs to be

```
<form method="POST" action="/panier">
```

There is a "=" missing and your method should be POST. I also notice you are hardcoding the action to "/panier". There are better ways in Laravel to build the action URL. Have a look at [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#named-routes)

UPDATE:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('panier')}}">
 ....
</form>

Route::POST('panier',[
  "uses" => "ProductController@addToCard",
  "as" => panier
]);

public function addToCard (Request $request){
      $input = $request->nb_serveurs;
      dd($input);
}
```

This should take your form, POST the values to a route called panier. That route will call your controller function called 'addToCard' in which you read the request. Then you can print via dd or more useful, store in a database or something

Comment: Thanks, i have another problem now, can you check my update on my post ?

Comment: I'm confused a bit. Do you want to add items (=POST) or do you want to list items (=GET). In any case, your route statement in your blade view should be {!! route('panier') !!} instead of action="{{ route('panier') }}

Comment: I want to list items but without variables in the URL isn't it POST method ? for now i want to make the dd helper work :p what's the difference between {{ and {!! ?

Comment: even if i do something like " Route::get('test',function(){
  return "test";
});" it pasts the same error..

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud Please keep a strictly professional language on SO.

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud Please consider answering your own question with the good code to help others in the future